# C# WPF GridSplitter внутри елемента

Tags: c#, wpf

В WPF GridSplitter работает внутри Grid. Но как сделать чтобы он был внутри елемента Grid чтобы получить примерно такой результат? Получается нажатие не между елементами а на title панель елемента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема? Отредактируйте шаблон `GridSplitter`

Comment: @АндрейNOP GridSplitter не работает вне Grid

Comment: Ну так поместите его в Grid. Какая панель там у вас, если не грид?